# ASP.net error. update panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

I am getting the below stated error in javascript. This error occurs when i try to cal update panel on button click

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'Panel|UpdatePanel1|
    <div id="up'.
```

Here is the UpdatePanel code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode=Conditional >
<ContentTemplate>

    <div  style="font-size:10px; font-weight:bold;display:none;" align=center  id="up_div" runat=server  >Apply Flat Rate to all days 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtflatrate" runat="server" Width=40  ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_apply" runat="server" Text="Go" UseSubmitBehavior=false OnClick="btn_apply_Click" />
    <asp:Table ID="tbl_charges" runat="server" EnableViewState=true>
    </asp:Table>
    Total: <asp:TextBox ID="txtttlrate" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div id="div_norates" runat=server visible=false style ="font-size:11px" class="red_font">
         <font color='red'>
        <center><b>Please make the neccessary changes before <i>creating a booking</i></b></font></CENTER><br/><br/><br/><center>The <i>season </i>for the date period chosen is <i>not set </i><br/> <center> <br/>OR </center> <br/>  The <i>room type </i>for the season is <i>not set</i>. <br/><br/><br/>Make neccessary changes in <i>seasons master</i></center>
    </div>

</ContentTemplate>

<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID=btn_calc EventName=click />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID=btn_apply EventName=click />

</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am not able to understand why this error is coming? Can anyone help me sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the aspx markup in incorrect causing the parser error. Check at `UpdateMode=Conditional`

If that is not the case please ensure that you are not using a Response.Write() in the async postback(see error message).